# UISlider frame error on ios7

Tags: frame, uislider, ios7

UISlider frame min width is 22, min height is 34.
Even if i set frame `CGRectMake(0,0,1,1)` it cannot change correctly.

```
UISlider *slider = [[UISlider alloc] init];
slider.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,1,1)
```

Comment: Would you please explain what do you want exactly?

Comment: Is the slider frame different between 6 and 7? I have this issue.

Comment: Even if i set frame CGRectMake(0,0,1,1) it's frame.size.width always 22px,and frame.size.height always 34px.@null

Answer (score 2):

I think, that Apple make 34 as minimum size of UISlider. Not 42, but 34

Try code:

```
UISlider *slider = [[UISlider alloc] init];
slider.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,36,36)
```

Comment: You can also go with: UISlider *slider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 36, 36)];

Comment: @Matt, yes, I know :) But I like to separate frame calculations and element initialization for better readability